# Getting error as "required a bean of type.....that could not be found"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have made a basic structure of a project named expense tracker, where I got error. Even though I have been trying to resolve it for a long time, it persists.

**Error :**

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field categoryRepository in com.app.expensetracker.service.CategoryServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.app.expensetracker.dao.CategoryRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.app.expensetracker.dao.CategoryRepository' in your configuration.

**CategoryRepository**

```
package com.app.expensetracker.dao;

import com.app.expensetracker.entity.Category;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, String> {

}
```

**Category**

```
package com.app.expensetracker.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString

public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="cat_id",nullable = false)
    private String cat_id;

    @Column(name="categoryName")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name="users")
    private List<String> users;

//    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
//    private  User user;

}
```

**CategoryService**

```
package com.app.expensetracker.service;

import com.app.expensetracker.dto.CategoryCreateRequest;
import com.app.expensetracker.entity.Category;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface CategoryService {

    Category createCategory(CategoryCreateRequest categoryCreateRequest);
    ResponseEntity<Optional<Category>> getCategoryById(String category_id);
    Category updateCategory(String categoryId, CategoryCreateRequest categoryCreateRequest);
    ResponseEntity<Optional<Category>> deleteCategoryById(String category_id);
}
```

**CategoryServiceImpl**

```
package com.app.expensetracker.service;
import com.app.expensetracker.dao.CategoryRepository;
import com.app.expensetracker.dto.CategoryCreateRequest;
import com.app.expensetracker.entity.Category;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService{
@Autowired
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Category createCategory(CategoryCreateRequest categoryCreateRequest){
        Category category = categoryCreateRequest.to();
        return categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Category>> getCategoryById(String category_id){
    
        Optional<Category> category =  categoryRepository.findById(category_id);
        if(category == null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        else{
            return ResponseEntity.ok(category);
        }
    
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Category updateCategory(String categoryId, CategoryCreateRequest categoryCreateRequest){
        Category category = categoryCreateRequest.to();
        return categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Category>> deleteCategoryById(String category_id){
        Optional<Category> category =  categoryRepository.findById(category_id);
        if(category == null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        else{
            categoryRepository.deleteById(category_id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(category);
        }
    }

}
```

**ExpenseTrackerApplication**

```
package com.app.expensetracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication //(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app.*")
//@EntityScan("com.app.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.expensetracker.repository")

public class ExpenseTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ExpenseTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before**

```
     @SpringBootApplication //(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
     //@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app.*")
     //@EntityScan("com.app.*")
     @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.expensetracker.repository")
     public class ExpenseTrackerApplication{
```

On disabling the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in the main class,the application started working.

**After**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class ExpenseTrackerApplication{
```

In my case, this worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem came from

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="cat_id",nullable = false)
private String cat_id;
```

because you are using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

on a `String` field that it is wrong because `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO`: either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB usually it is `long`, `short` or `int`, not `String`.

To fix it you have to set it something like it:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "cat_id", nullable = false)
private String cat_id;
```

**UPDATE:**

After analyze the github repo of project, I could say that the problem it`s in` ExpenseTrackerApplication` main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
        (exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ExpenseTrackerApplication {...}
```

you have to rewrite it to

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExpenseTrackerApplication {...}
```

For future if you want to have a auto configuration datasource in the project don`t exclude it.

Also after correct it you are going to have a problem related to sql `Driver`.

To fix it just add next one param into `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Many problems related to relations between your entities that you will have to handle it on your own, after all my mentions.

Comment: In warning logs , it shows "UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryService': Error creating bean with name 'categoryServiceImpl' : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.expensetracker.dao.CategoryRepository' available:"

Comment: I don’t see any problems, Could you share it on GitHub and give the GitHub link to the repository here ?

Comment: This is the GitHub link - https://github.com/giribala999/expenseTracker/tree/vc-4-new

Comment: Yes, I did manage to solve your problem and also I updated my answer. Could you check ?

Comment: You could accept my answer, if someone else in the future will have the same problem as you.

Comment: I am grateful that you took the time to check .On disabling EnableJpaRepositories annotation ,the application is working. Others points like, (exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) and, the relations between the entities part, were commented and disabled in the Github, they were already not the part of code. So, again saw the main class ,only @EnableJpaRepositories was active, on commenting it, the application started.  And thank you! for mentioning previously, that on a String field it is wrong to set strategy = GenerationType.AUTO. I studied and implemented after your mention .